# SCSS not working with Angular 11 after update

Tags: angular, sass

I recently updated my global Angular CLI with the command

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

and now my angular apps are not compiling SCSS files.

What should I do?

**Edit**: Okay so I created a new app with CSS, the same issue persists. Inline-styles are working though.

File: app.component.css

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
}
```

None of these styles seem to apply to the 'body'.